# Why does mold grow on silicone caulk?

Tags: mycology

I notice mold likes to grow on silicone caulk. I find it odd since silicone is mostly inorganic and doesn't contain any nutrients for mold to grow on unlike soil and clothing. Can mold metabolize silicon?

Comment: Can you please post a picture?

Comment: The EPA has outlawed certain fungicides from time to time ; it takes time for manufacturers to develop new ones. I have caulk around some windows that has turned black with mold but a nearby window with different caulk is still white . The windows are about 10 years old . 25 year old original caulk is still white . (These are all exterior exposures). It depends on the mold inhibitors available at the time.

Answer (score 3):

[This product brochure](https://db1736767dbd5e7094bb-d61bbc5d0b342a54145a236e2d5d1ebf.ssl.cf4.rackcdn.com/Product/c03ace49-8c57-4b7d-bce0-be2076e18d68.pdf) seems to give a reasonable explanation:

> The following conditions help to form mould on sealants:
>
> - High air humidity with little movement of air, eg: in bathrooms, showers, kitchens etc.
> - Warmth
> - Nutrients in the form of organic deposits. e.g. residues from body care materials
>     such as soap, shower gel etc.
>
> Since elastic silicone joints have low thermal conductivity they are the warmest part of a tiled surface and where mould thrives best, in combination with organic residues and moisture.